# Unable to insert new value in an empty dataFrame within FOR loop : Error - IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to insert a row in EMPTY DataFrame in FOR loop if the condition meets. I'm getting IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Below is my code:

```
 women = pd.DataFrame(columns= ["Survival_Rate"])
for i in range(len(titanic_train_data.Sex)):
    if (titanic_train_data.Sex[i] == 'female'):
        women['Survival_Rate'][i] = ([titanic_train_data.Survived[i]])
```

In order to accomplish above, I've also tried to use APPEND method but that is also not working & I'm getting TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ''; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

```
women = pd.DataFrame(columns= ["Survival_Rate"])
for i in range(len(titanic_train_data.Sex)):
    if (titanic_train_data.Sex[i] == 'female'):
        women['Survival_Rate'].append([titanic_train_data.Survived[i]])
```

Can any one please share insights on above issue and what mistake I'm doing.
Awaiting for reply.

Regards, 
Mukul

Comment: If you're getting the same error in both codes, I'm almost sure that the problem is with `titanic_train_data` try printing `titanic_train_data.Sex[1]` or `titanic_train_data.Sex[1]` to see if that's the problem

Comment: @mukul munjal, what are you trying to achieve by using ** ? I do not think you need a loop here. Can you post the sample data and expected result?

Comment: @Gamopo, There is no problem with the TRAINING dataset. I've tried printing this titanic_train_data.Sex[1] , its working as expected.

Comment: @XXavier, thanks.
Sex Survived
male 0
female 1
female 1
female 1
male 0

 My intention here is to check the survived value wherever the SEX is FEMALE and if this check is true then insert SURVIVED value in EMPTY Dataframe  women under ['Survival_Rate'] column.

Comment: @XXavier, please ignore **, that was typo error.

Answer (score 0):

Was missing **LOC** function. Working fine now.

```
for i in range(len(titanic_train_data.Sex)):
    if (titanic_train_data.Sex[i] == 'female'):
        women.Survived.loc[i] = titanic_train_data.Survived[i]
```